# Obtener solo las Columnas deseadas en la consulta con la anotacion @QUERY

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data

Estoy realizando una consulta a la BD de la siguente manera:

```
        (repository)
        @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM usuario u WHERE u.nombre = nombre",
        nativeQuery = true)
        List<Usuario> findAllActiveUsersNative(String nombre);

        (Controller)
        @GetMapping
        public ResponseEntity<List<Usuario>> getall(String nombre)throws Throwable {
        List<Usuario> nombres = usuarioRepository.findAllActiveUsersNative(nombre);
                   if (nombres.isEmpty())
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(nombres);
}

sin ningun problema puedo obtener la consulta y traer todas las columnas de la siguente manera :

    {"id":1,"nombre":"user","nombreUsuario":"user","email":"user@user","password":"$2a$10$3np9pkddv.EI0v4AuNrHgONVCI3JdLVGzR5SHkyiZZPgMPbofZmjW","tokenPassword":null,"cedula":"","roles":[{"id":2,"rolNombre":"ROLE_USER"}]},{"id":2,"nombre":"admin","nombreUsuario":"admin","email":"admin@admin","password":"$2a$10$7durqOtkJwB4.czs9wAOBu.hg.otH1xCv6ZeJsqRqARjECz7ikITO","tokenPassword":null,"cedula":"","roles":[{"id":1,"rolNombre":"ROLE_ADMIN"}]},{"id":3,"nombre":"caja","nombreUsuario":"caja","email":"caja@caja","password":"$2a$10$AdmGVmQzXUu0.8qfYowAuu9iNAymNXJdxH9fuf6PRbr8AGg8cW6ka","tokenPassword":null,"cedula":"","roles":[{"id":3,"rolNombre":"ROLE_CAJA"}]}
```

mi problema es que al especificar que solo traiga las columnas necesarias de la siguente manera :

```
             (repository)
             @Query(value = "SELECT u.nombre, u.email FROM usuario u WHERE u.nombre = nombre",
        nativeQuery = true)
         List<Usuario> findAllActiveUsersNative(String nombre);

        (Controller)
        @GetMapping
        public ResponseEntity<List<Usuario>> getall(String nombre)throws Throwable {
        List<Usuario> nombres = usuarioRepository.findAllActiveUsersNative(nombre);
                   if (nombres.isEmpty())
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(nombres);
}
```

me esta generando el siguente error :

```
     "message": "could not execute query; SQL [SELECT u.nombre, u.email FROM usuario u WHERE u.nombre = nombre]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query",
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad no entiendo la sintaxis necesaria para poder consultar solo las columnas requeridas ejemplo : email y nombre nada mas...

aqui como esta mi modelo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que me sorprende es que la primera no te de ningún error:

```
SELECT * 
FROM usuario u 
WHERE u.nombre = nombre
```

Asumo que el intérprete entiende que `nombre` y `u.nombre` son el mismo campo, por lo que esa consulta sería equivalente a

```
SELECT * FROM usuario u WHERE 1 = 1 --siempre es verdad
```

Te faltan los dos puntos delante del parámetro para indicar que debe ser sustituido por el valor correspondiente:

```java
@Query(
  value = "SELECT u.nombre, u.email FROM usuario u WHERE u.nombre = :nombre",
  nativeQuery = true
)
List<Usuario> findAllActiveUsersNative(String nombre);
```

Y después de eso, el problema es que no puedes seleccionar de ese modo sólo algunos de los campos, necesitarías crear otra clase Java que fuese una versión "abreviada" de esta primera que sólo tenga los getters y setters correspondientes.